# WPF Call a function when another window calls it

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a login window in my WPF application, which I'm about to finish:

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a main window, which creates the login window.

In the login window, when the user logs in, I want to send an event "LoginSuccess".

In the main window, which is listening to the login window' events, a function get called.

In fact, I'm trying to do something like that:

```
public App()
{
    Window LoginWindow = new ...();
    LoginWindow.LoginSucceed += LoginSucceed;
}

void LoginSucceed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ....
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a LoginSucceed event in your LoginWindow.xaml.cs class if you haven't already.

Create a class level variable that looks something like this:

`public event RoutedEventHandler LoginSucceed;`

After validating the user, you can trigger this event:

`LoginSucceed(this, null)`

You can then hook up to this event from your main window like you have above.
Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Exactly, thanks! But I have a problem: in App.xaml, I'm creating a Window object, and so I can't do `LoginWindow.LoginSucceed += fnc`. How can I access this event from my main window?

Comment: Any reason in particular that your creating a Window object?  Normally, I set things up in the MainWindow.xaml.cs class

Comment: I'm using Modern UI Library and I send parameters directly by creating  a ModernWindow object. But nevermind, I found that I can use LoginPage.Content to access my class directly. Thanks!